# Perl LFTP Pipe Using SSH Key

Tags: perl, ssh, sftp, lftp

I can currently connect to an SFTP server using a username/password combination:

```
print "Attempting connection...\n";

open( my $LFTP,'|-', "lftp -u $ftpuser,'$ftppwd' -e open -p $ftpport $ftpserver" ) or die "Cannot open lftp: $!";

print $LFTP <<"END";
                    ls
END
close($LFTP); # die unless lftp exit code is 0

exit 0;
```

How can change this code to connect to a different server using an SSH key which is encrypted with a passphrase?

This is what I've tried:

```
print "Attempting connection...\n";

# $ftppwd is blank now!

open( my $LFTP,'|-', "lftp -u $ftpuser,'$ftppwd' -e 'set sftp:connect-program \"ssh -a -x -i $keypath\"; open $ftpserver;'" ) or die "Cannot open lftp: $!";

print $LFTP <<"END";
                                ls
END
close($LFTP); # die unless lftp exit code is 0
exit 0;
```

The output is stuck at:

```
Attempting connection...
`ls' at 0 [Connecting...]
```

Thank you in advance for any help..

Comment: Why are not you using a Perl module for that (Net::SFTP::Foreign)?

Answer (score 0):

Add -u option to the open command inside -e argument and use the pass phrase as the password. You should also use url syntax to select the sftp protocol, e.g. sftp://user:phrase@server